# Formal Laurent series in more variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, laurent-series

The formal Laurent series in one variables is

$$\begin{equation} \mathbb{C}((t))=\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{C}[[t]])=\mathbb{C}[[t]][\frac{1}{t}] \end{equation}$$

What is the difference between this field and

$$\begin{equation} \bigg\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{n}t^{n}\quad\text{such that}\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \ a_{n}\in\mathbb{C}\}\bigg\}\end{equation}$$

In more variables what is the difference with this case in the definition?

Comment: You meant $Frac(\Bbb{C}[[t]])$ (fraction field), each of its element is of the form $ \sum_{n\ge -N} a_n t^n$ for some finite $N$. On the other hand $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} a_n t^n$ is not a ring, you can't multiply $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} t^n$ with itself, you need to add some decay condition on the $a_n$ to get a ring of analytic functions (on some annulus of $\Bbb{C}$) obtaining a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring of formal Laurent series comprises formal series $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}a_nt^n$, where, for some $i \in \Bbb{Z}$, the $a_n$ with $n < i$ are all zero: so we could write the formal series as $\sum_{n=i}^\infty a_nt^n$. This reflects the fact that there is only one pair of square brackets round $\frac{1}{t}$ in $\Bbb{C}[[t]][\frac{1}{t}]$ - a notation that really means $\Bbb{C}[[t]][u]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal $(tu - 1)$. As mentioned in a comment this is the same as the field of fractions of the ring of formal power series $\Bbb{C}[[t]]$.

The element $tu - 1$ is a unit in the ring of formal power series $\Bbb{C}[[t, u]]$, implying that the quotient ring $\Bbb{C}[[t, u]]/(tu - 1) = \{0\}$. This reflects the fact that the convolution product doesn't make sense if you allow non-zero coefficients $a_n$ for negative values of $n$ of arbitrarily large absolute value.

If you are looking at formal Laurent series in more than one variable, the same considerations apply: e.g., $\Bbb{C}[[t, v]][\frac{1}{t}, \frac{1}{v}]$ means $\Bbb{C}[[t, v]][u, w]/(tu - 1, vw - 1)$ and comprises formal series $\sum_{m,n \in \Bbb{Z}}a_{mn}t^mv^n$, where at most finitely many $a_{mn}$ with $m < 0$ or $n < 0$ are non-zero.

Comment: Thanks. You are right and my notation was wrong. I think it is now fixed.

Comment: It seems your description of elements of $$\mathbb{C}[\![ t,v ]\!][t^{-1},v^{-1}]$$ might have a small error. For example, it excludes elements like $$\frac{1}{v(1-t)}$$.